# Will downloading files locally from Google Colab's workspace use my internet or Colab's?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a large file in my Google Colab Workspace. I want to download it to my local machine using the command `files.download(name of the file)`. Will this use my internet or Colab's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both. Files downloaded from Colab will use the Internet connection of the client machine to receive the data, which will have been sent using the Internet connection of the Colab backend.

To inspect the file size, hover over the file in the file browser. In the image below, for example, the file is 294 kilobytes.
[image]

FYI, you can download by right clicking on the file and selecting download, which is a bit simpler than executing the code snippet in your question.

Comment: Is it possible to know approximately how much internet of the client is used (out of the total used in terms of percentage)?

Comment: Sure, I edited the answer to illustrate inspecting file sizes.