# In Google Colab, when loading files from an external site to a Google Drive directory using the wget command, will it use my internet or Colab's?

Tags: google-colaboratory, wget

I am loading a file to a Google Drive directory using the wget command in my Colab notebook as shown below:

```
!wget --directory-prefix='/path_to_directory/' http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip
```

I see the download proceeds with a speed of around 2-3 MB/s.

As I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864610/will-downloading-files-locally-from-google-colabs-workspace-use-my-internet-or) answer, downloading files locally would use both, Colab's internet and my internet.

In case the destination folder is on Google Drive, will it use my internet for the load?

Answer (score 0):

Colab is a VM, and it's hosted on google's servers,

Anything you do, happens there, If run command: `rm -rf /*` it'll run there.

but when you upload the files, it'll use both internet, your for uploading, and colab's VM for downloading.